# Vim not showing longer unicode characters

Tags: vim, unicode

I wanted to add an unicode image of [cat](http://unicode-table.com/en/1F431/) to my file, but when I press `ctrl+v u 1 f 4 3 1` the result is `ὃ1` rather than .

Vim always stops reading the code after the fourth character and then it just prints the number 1 at the end. It does the same thing when I try to just paste the cat from clipboard. All unicode characters with four digit codes work just fine.

Why is it so? How can I use longer unicode codes in vim?

Comment: What is the current file's encoding? `set fileencoding?` (with the `?`). If it’s not `utf-8` or similar, you’re out of luck, because the cat emoji won’t be representable in older encodings (like `latin-1`).

Comment: It is my `.bashrc` and it is in `utf-8` for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [`:help i_CTRL-V_digit`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-V_digit). You need to start the sequence with an upper-case `U`, because the cat emoji is outside the [basic multilingual plane](https://codepoints.net/basic_multilingual_plane) (the codepoints from U+0000 to U+FFFF).

Comment: And to end the input I use any non-numeric key. Thanks alot!